# FBAdViewControllerProxy is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdViewControllerProxy

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, facebook-audience-network

I Integrated FB audience network and when I run the app it crushes and I get this exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FBFinalClassViolationException', reason: 'FBAdViewControllerProxy is a final class and cannot be subclassed. FBAdViewControllerProxy'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 11
```

And it's working fine when I switch to Android and I tried to edit Podfile to:

```
target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '~> 6.2.0'
end
```

and I even deleted everything in the Podfile and build then clean but it seems it has no effect. maybe I am missing something, can someone please help?

Comment: Sounds like something is trying to derive from `FBAdViewControllerProxy` like e.g. `public class MyProxy : FBAdViewControllerProxy{ ...}` but as the error says the `FBAdViewControllerProxy` is marked as final and therefore can not be extended

Comment: But all I did is add the fb audience SDK to the project, that means this bug is in the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to change podfile to:

```
target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do
end
target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '~> 6.2.0'
end
```

and then open the project in terminal and run : `pod install`